# Reusable view layout in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, reusability

In my project, I have a lot of views containing a list of navigation links. I've made it separated as a view and using @include('menu') for other views. However, depending of each view, I want to ask some classes (for styling) to certain elements and I don't know how to do that

menu.blade.php

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="menu-item active">
     <a href="#">Product Manager</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="#">Categories Manager</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="#">Order Manager</a>
   </li>     
</ul>
```

More explanation: If the view is Product Manager, I want to add "active" only on the first "li" element...

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item @if (Request::is('product-manager*')) active @endif">
   <a href="product-manager">Product Manager</a>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item @if (Request::is('categories-manager*')) active @endif">
  <a href="categories-manager">Categories Manager</a>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item @if (Request::is('order-manager*')) active @endif">
  <a href="order-manager">Order Manager</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If can build your menu.blade.php like the following:

```
<?php
  $activeMenu = isset($activeMenu) ? $activeMenu : '';
  $menuItems = [
      'Product Manager' => '#',
      'Categories Manager' => '#',
      'Order Manager' => '#',
  ];
?>
<ul class="menu">
  @foreach($menuItems as $name => $link)
    <li class="menu-item {{ $activeMenu === $name ? 'active' : ''}}">
      <a href="{{ $link }}">{{ $name }}</a>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

This allows you to define your menu items easily in a single array, and when it loops through rendering each menu item it will check if it needs to add the active class.

Inside of your other views, when you use @include('menu') you can pass in an optional argument to set the active menu item:

```
{{-- Menu without any item active --}}
@include('menu')

{{-- Menu with Product Manager active --}}
@include('menu', ['activeMenu' => 'Product Manager'])

{{-- Menu with Order Manager active --}}
@include('menu', ['activeMenu' => 'Order Manager'])
```